# How to create bulk multimedia components using Tridion coreservice

Tags: component

We have to create bulk multimedia components along with metadata using Tridion core service in c#. As we are creating each one individually by calling create() method of core service it is nearly taking 12 sec time for each. By this, we are facing timeout issue.

So is there any way to create all components through a single call.

Could you please do needful.

Thanks & Regards,
Shruthi

Answer (score 1):

It does not sound normal that creating a single item takes 12 seconds; you should be looking into optimizing your database.

Regardless, it is not clear to me why you are facing timeout issues. Are you creating multiple items in a single transaction (and getting a transaction timeout)?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TREX Shruthi.

I presume you're looking to import into the CMS and not media manager (would be useful to include the version info and what you've tried with your questions).

- Have you looked at the possibility of using WebDAV?
- Can you increase the timeout and just run out of hours?